# How to read txt line by line from a pdf file

Tags: file-io, python-2.7

```
import pyPdf 
f= open('jayabal_appt.pdf','rb')
pdfl = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(f)
output = pyPdf.PdfFileWriter()
content=""
for i in range(0,1):
    content += pdfl.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
outpu = open('b.txt','wb')
outpu.write(content)
f.close()
outpu.close()
```

This is not writing the content of a pdf to a txt file... what shld i do???

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through every page and call `extractText()` like so:

```
content = ""
for i in range(0, num_pages):
    content += pdfl.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
```

Once you have the full contents you can easily split the lines via the '\n' separator.

EDIT:
Check after the for-loop, whether the variable `contents` even contains any text. Not all PDF files contain text information.

Comment: import pyPdf 
    f= open('jayabal_appt.pdf','rb')
    pdfl = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(f)
    output = pyPdf.PdfFileWriter()
    content=""
    for i in range(0,1):
        content += pdfl.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    output.addPage(pdfl.getPage(0))
    outpu = open('b.txt','wb')
    outpu.write(content)
    f.close()
    outpu.close()     will this wrk???

Comment: @VenkatramanK Please update your question and add the formatted code there. But from what I can read you have a few typos in your code.